# DJANGo Ajax request sometime return response and some time error

Tags: python, ajax, django

error::

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:9000/xyz/test 0 ()

```
path('test', views.test,name="test")

def test(request):
    json_data= json.dumps({"query_id":"213"})
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')

function call_ajax(){
    $.post({
        url: "{%url 'home:test'%}",
        data: {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.query_id);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:9000/xyz/test 0 ()

Comment: no response not even response code